# LibGit2Sharp: error FS0229: Error opening binary file -> bad cli header, rva 0

Tags: c#, f#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I installed LibGit2Sharp and LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries with paket (first last stable version, then prerelease) and I am trying to use it in an F# script, but I keep getting this error:

> Script1.fsx(3,1): error FS0229: Error opening binary file
>   '../packages\LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries\runtimes\win7-x64\native\git2-381caf5.dll':
>   ../packages\LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries\runtimes\win7-x64\native\git2-381caf5.dll:
>   bad cli header, rva 0
>
> Script1.fsx(3,1): error FS3160: Problem reading assembly '': Exception
>   of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger+StopProcessing' was
>   thrown.

I also tried referencing it in a C# project (VS2015 -> tried diff target frameworks: 4, 4.5.2 and 4.6.1), but I'm getting this error:

[image: error adding reference]

Same errors with the last stable version.
Any idea what I'm doing incorrect?

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to reference C or C++ dlls in .NET. Can you show how you are referencing libgit2 in you code. Why do you need libgit btw? There are windows git clients.

Comment: I added the folder where the native libraries should reside. You don't need to reference it directly, but you do need to reference LibGit2Sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably reference (in VS or via `#r` in FSI):

> `#r @"..\packages\LibGit2Sharp.0.23.0-pre20160803182831\lib\net40\LibGit2Sharp.dll"`

I could do

```
open LibGit2Sharp
let myrepo = new Repository(@"..\Projects\StackOverflow5")
```

The error you got is really referring to the native libgit2 libraries and you don't need to reference them directly. However it's possible the `LibGit2Sharp` cannot find them. In that case place the x64 (or x86 if you're still stuck in 32-bit) `git2-381-caf5.dll` into the same folder where `LibGit2Sharp.dll` lives. In this case that's the same folder I'm referencing above:

> \packages\LibGit2Sharp.0.23.0-pre20160803182831\lib\net40\

Comment: thank you so much, I would not have figured that out myself! Copying the file worked :-)

Comment: @Selketjah glad that solved it. This happens when native libraries are wrapped in .Net.